# Cartesian product of two categorical variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

Let a DataFrame which have among other two categorical variables one has `child young mature old` classes and other has `male female` classes.

How could I have systematically a new column `'Sex_Age'` with classes `male_child, female_child, male_young, female_young, male_mature, female_mature, male_old, female_old`?

In two cases:

1. I don't want this new categorical variable really added to my DataFrame but only want use it's concept and say, draw  `jitter plot` which have eight bunch of points.
2. I want to add this new categorical variable to my DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Sex':['male', 'female',\
         'male', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'male',\
        'male', 'female'], 'Age':['child', 'old', 'mature',\
        'young', 'young', 'mature', 'child', 'child', 'child'],
                  'HairLength':[2,30,8,15,9,35,3,5,6]})
df
```

**In case 1:** I want `jitter plot` of `'HairLength'` by 8 bunch in one figure corresponding to 8 cases: `male_child, female_mature, ...`  and I'm not interested in the new column.

**In case 2:** I'm interested in adding a `'Sex_Age'` column to my `DateFrame` with true data such as `male_child` and so on.

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, can you please clarify: `I don't want this new categorical variable really added to my DataFrame` but then `I want to add this new categorical variable to my DataFrame`

Comment: I did as you said @yatu

Answer (score 0):

My example DataFrame is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['male', 'female', 'male'], 'B':['one', 'two', 'three']})
```

So you can use function get_dummies from pandas:

```
pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['A', 'B'])
```

And output will be:

```
    A_female    A_male  B_one   B_three B_two
0          0         1      1         0     0
1          1         0      0         0     1
2          0         1      0         1     0
```

And you can use it to draw, like (but it isn't jitter plot):

```
pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['A', 'B']).plot(kind='bar')
```

Or concatenate to your DataFrameWriter with:

```
df = df.join(pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['A', 'B']))
```